# Why didn't the Hungarians help the battle of Kosovo?

Tags: ottoman-empire, battle, hungary, the-balkans, serbia

I am curious why the Hungarians, as the first neighbor of then Serbia and Bosnia, who sent troops to confront the invasion of the Ottomans, didn't also participate given that it was obvious that the Ottomans would target them next after defeating the Serbs/Bosnians.

E.g. were there diplomatic failures, intelligence gathering failures, or simple political misalignments that cultivated their shortsightedness?

Comment: You should know the procedure by now. Please edit basic details (such as the date of the battle and how it turned out) into the question.  You should also tell us if the research you've already done has turned up unsatisfactory results, so potential answerers avoid blins alleys.

Comment: I thought that anyone who actually knows an answer would know the details of this  rather relevant historic battle

Comment: @amphibient Perhaps, but others coming to this site after you've got your answer might be better informed because of it (and it might trigger memories in people who know the answer, but need more context to prompt it).

Comment: It is an issue of courtesy, of community standards, and the opportunity to educate.  Those who know the answer might know the basics, but we're also here to point out interesting little corners of knowledge to those who don't know the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Battle of Kosovo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kosovo) took place on June 15, 1389

> **Question:** 
>   Why didn't the Hungarians help the battle of Kosovo?

**Short Answer:**

1. Hungary was a powerful country but had its own troubles to deal with prior to dealing with the Ottomans.
2. The Serbians were Eastern Orthodox Christians, Hungarians were Catholic.  Thus they were not traditional allies.
3. Hungary didn't really perceive the Ottomans as a serious threat until Serbia's acceptance of their rule in 1390 which effectively brought the Ottoman Empire to Hungary's frontier.

**Detailed Answer:**

The **[Kingdom of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Hungary_(1301%E2%80%931526)#Interregnum_(1301%E2%80%931323))** reached the peak of its power under **[Louis the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_I_of_Hungary)** (1342–1382) who was a superior military leader.  When Louis died in 1382, his daughter **[Mary, Queen of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary,_Queen_of_Hungary)** was crowned. However, most of Hungary's noblemen objected being ruled by a woman.  A rival for Mary's crown, **[Charles III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_III_of_Naples)**, arrived from Naples in 1385 and claimed Mary's throne.  Although Mary was forced to abdicate, and Charles was elected King by the Hungarian Diet, Mary's supporters murdered Charles in Feb 1386.  A Catholic Bishop got involved and tried to nominate Charles's infant son to the crown in the same year Charles was murdered.  They succeeded in capturing Queen Mary.  Eventually Queen Mary's husband ([Sigismund of Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigismund,_Holy_Roman_Emperor)) emerged as the compromise candidate for the throne of Hungary in July 1386.   Sigismund was consolidating his power and defending his crown from Queen Mary's sister (**[Queen Jadwiga of Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jadwiga_of_Poland)**), who invaded and was defeated in 1395.

It wasn't until Serbia accepted the Ottoman Sultan's suzerainty (1390), and brought the Ottoman empire to the boarders of southern Hungary that Sigismund perceived them as a threat. He didn't have the opportunity to attack them until 1396 at the **[Battle of Nicopolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Nicopolis)**.

**[Sigismund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigismund,_Holy_Roman_Emperor)** was defeated at Nicopolis, but eventually became King of Germany, King of Bohemia, and in 1433, Holy Roman Emperor.

**Sources:**

- **[Battle of Kosovo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kosovo)**
- **[Kingdom of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Hungary_(1301%E2%80%931526)#Interregnum_(1301%E2%80%931323))**
- **[Louis I of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_I_of_Hungary)**
- **[Mary, Queen of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary,_Queen_of_Hungary)**
- **[Charles III of Naples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_III_of_Naples)**
- **[Battle of Nicopolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Nicopolis)**

Comment: Solid answer, but you should also mention Catholic - Orthodox divide, that also kept Christians from uniting against Ottoman Islamic invasion .

Comment: @rs.29  That is a very good point.  With your permission I added it to my answer.  I will have to read up on the extent of religious animosity between the Hungarians and Serbs specifically, but I am aware of animosity during the crusades and across wider areas of Europe.  Thank You.

Comment: It all started with Fourth Crusade and sack of Constantinople. Although not directly related to Serbia and Hungary, it showed that Catholic army could not be trusted to behave properly in "schismatic" (i.e. Orthodox) lands. Similar things happened later, after the battle of Kosovo, during the crusade that culminated with Battle of Nicopolis in 1396. Overall, there was a deep mistrust, from what we know Lazar Hrebeljanovic, sensing impeding war with the Turks tried to secure northern border from Hungarian incursions, but never pondered alliance.

Comment: Note that already in 1390, not a year after his death, Hungarians started raiding weakened Serbia. This led his wife Milica to accept suzerainty of Ottomans. This of course does not mean that relations between Hungarians and Serbs were always bad, Lazar himself was for some time vassal of Hungarian king and even partially participated in Hungarian internal strife. But it does show that Serbs viewed Hungary as lesser evil compared to Ottoman Empire, not as Christian brothers.

Comment: Not really. In 1390 Milica was forced to accept Ottoman suzerainty by appearance of another Ottoman army at Serbian borders (and she simply didn't have troops to oppose them).  Latter her son Stefan (and his successor Đurađ) often allied with Hungarians against Turks, but all of those alliances were uneasy, with each side not completely trusting the other (one of the reasons they ultimately failed to stop Ottoman expansion). But overall Serbs did prefer Hungarians to Turks.

Comment: One more things to mention, Milica was forced to give her daughter Olivera to a harem of Ottoman sultan Bayezid I. It is rumored that she neutered her before the marriage, in order not to have "pagan" children. This shows how hard it was for her to accept Ottomans as overlords. I'm sure she would prefer Hungarians, if it was possible at this time.

Comment: @rs.29 to be frank, ideological alignments rarely worked even between the Catholics. Centuries later the Hungarians themselves often got aligned with the Ottomans agains the Catholic Habsburg, and vice versa. International relationships were often much more hostile and unreliable then what would one expect

Comment: @Greg It is not a matter or ideology or temporary convenient alliance. It is more of feeling about something being alien. To contemporary Orthodox nobles, Catholics were to a degree alien, but not so much as Muslims. Of course vice versa is also true.

Comment: @rs.29 I don’t know how they felt, only know how they done. Hungarian - Ottoman alliances against other Catholics definitely happened often, and were a common theme for most Hungarian revolutions. Also, internal completion of nobility were pretty strong, often unintentionally supporting the Ottoman cause.

Comment: @Greg There were no major Hungarian - Ottoman alliances during Middle Ages, at least I could not remember any significant :) But there were numerous Hungarian - Ottoman wars. Religion was much important in M.A. compared to let's say Napoleonic era.

Comment: @rs.29 It is true that there were no alliances at the time when the Ottoman goal was full invasion of the area, and Hungary was still independent. However I do not agree that religion would have been much more important in term of alliances in the area in late 1400s than in eg in the 1600s or 1700s. Before that the Hungarians were more preoccupied by internal conflicts and conflicts with western neighbors than any Islamic threat.

Comment: @Greg I would disagree. In fact, actions vs Ottomans in 15th century were deemed as Crusades https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusades#Late_Middle_Ages_and_Renaissance . Only latter Christian powers started to negotiate with Turks (France foremost because they were not directly threatened)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitulations_of_the_Ottoman_Empire . As late as 1683 Christian wars vs Ottomans had strong religious undertones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Vienna#Religious_significance

Comment: @rs.29 Funny you site he Battle of Vienna. An age when Hungarians were actively fighting against the Habsburgs often in alliance with Ottomans (also clearly indicated even in Wikipedia page you cite). Of course, religion played a role here, but another way: Ottomans were often more tolerant with Lutherans and Calvinist, and less threat to religious freedom, than Habsburgs.

Comment: @Greg That is exactly the point - Emeric Thököly and his followers were Lutherans, therefore they were seen as "traitors" and "Turkish servants" by majority in Catholic Hungary. His army was made mostly from Turks (not Hungarians) and his vassal state (Upper Hungary) lasted only 2-3 years. In fact, this event was huge propaganda tool for Catholics in Central and Eastern Europe. They were free to portray Protestants as a traitorous sect that "helps the Turks" and as a result Catholicism was not seriously challenged unlike West Europe.